# Alternating class not found error when using session handler

Tags: php, session

First of all, if it's relevant, this is in a session handler. This function is the one that writes to the database and is passed to `session_set_save_handler` along with my other functions like this

```
session_set_save_handler('sess_open', 'sess_close', 'sess_read', 'sess_write', 'sess_destroy', 'sess_gc');
```

I have this chunk of code...

```
$qid = "select count(*) as total
        from zen_sessions
        where sesskey = '" . $key . "'";

if(!class_exists('DB'))
    require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/class/DB.class.php';
var_dump(new DB());                      //this is line 109
$total = DB::select_one($qid);
```

the conditional and `var_dump` are for testing. Oddly enough sometimes it works fine while others it gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in /path/to/file/session_functions.php on line 109
```

I cannot figure how this wouldn't crash at the require instead of the `var_dump` and why only sometimes?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

edit-- response to comment/question:

The result of the following code

```
var_dump(class_exists('DB', false)); 
var_dump(is_file(dirname(__DIR__).'/class/DB.class.php'));
```

is:

```
bool(false) bool(true)
```

before trying to require it and the same result after the require(or true true when it doesn't give me an error)
Looks something like:

```
bool(true) bool(true) object(DB)#3 (0) { }
```

The previous code chunk is the result about once out of every 5 page loads while the error is the result the other 4.

Edit2 -- new findings.

Even more curious is according to the [manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) I should never see these debugging statements or errors

> Note:
>
> The "write" handler is not executed until after the output stream is
>   closed. Thus, output from debugging statements in the "write" handler
>   will never be seen in the browser. If debugging output is necessary,
>   it is  suggested that the debug output be written to a file instead.

Edit 3 - A Note for clarity:

The `DB` class Should have been autoloaded(and is everywhere else in the application) the `class_exists` and require are simply there for testing purposes.

Edit 4 - Stack trace

I decided to try and throw an exception when the class isn't found to see the stack trace, this is what I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DB Class Not Found.' 
in /path/to/file/session_functions.php:108 
Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: sess_write('074dabb967260e9...', 'securityToken|s...') 
#1 {main} thrown in /path/to/file/session_functions.php on line 108
```

Comment: What if you do `class_exists('DB', false)` instead? + `var_dump(is_file(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/class/DB.class.php'));` + `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @zerkms see my edit. Pretty much the same result.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White That's a pretty big leap to make when you don't know where `$key` is coming from. Thanks for the concern though.

Comment: to the average reader stumbling on your question, they might copy the pattern. so i like put a warning up.

Comment: @DanielA.White Fair enough.

Comment: `object(DB)#3 (0) { } `--- it means an object was created. What is the problem then?

Comment: @zerkms problem is the object is only created once out of about every 5 times with an error being the result the other 4.

Comment: just in case: can you provide the contents of DB.class.php?

Comment: Regarding Edit2, you may want to add a var_dump(debug_backtrace()) to see how you actually get there. Maybe your code is not actually called only when you think it is?

Comment: not sure it is a good idea to put PHP into compile mode while executing a function anyway. Try including the DB class before you start doing anything with sessions. Have you tried adding the DB class unconditionally as part of your 'bootstrap' code? Is there ny conditional logic in the 'DB' script that can cause the class to npt be defined?

Comment: For me, at the beginning you should simple require file with DB at the beginning of your script with the full path (probably in index.php file) without using `class_exists` function.

Comment: @RyanVincent @Marcin Nabialek The `class_exists` is just for debugging. DB is autoloaded long before this function is called in an initializer file, which is the first thing included in the file executing the function. - The `auloload` is after session_start() though. If that matters

Comment: @KevinHorst You can find a source very similar to the DB class here https://github.com/flyinbryan125/DB-Helper

Comment: Are you using 'namespaces'? Start from first principles with code that doesn't work... Do the 'class_check' for 'DB' often. Starting immediately after the point where you think it should have been loaded. Then move that check towards the code causing bother. Throw an exception if the 'DB' class is not found. Always ensure that classes are explicitly loaded before you use them. Either use an 'autoloader' or 'include_once'. Always load the class unconditionally if it is used on most runs of the program.

Comment: @RyanVincent No namespaces. It is loaded with an autoloader. Then there is this check to make 100% sure it is loaded and it still fails 75% of the time. If it failed 100% of the time I could continue until I found the point of failure. The issue is it DOES work just not consistently.

Comment: please mention your db class some code such as class name

Comment: I noticed you saying  "The auloload is after session_start() though" That does matter, it should be available before the session_start().

Comment: Thanks Sander, I'll give that a shot, I just always have `session_start()` as very first line to avoid problems. But that may be the issue.

Comment: @SanderVisser issue persists. I tried explicitly including the DB class before starting the session as well as autoloading before starting the session, neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of that *may* be causing this, is from a notice in the PHP docs for session_set_save_handler:

> Warning
>
> Current working directory is changed with some SAPIs if session is closed in the script termination. It is possible to close the session earlier with session_write_close().

From what you are experiencing, I am guessing the current working directory is changed, so `require_once` doesn't find the file.

I would *try* adding `session_write_close();` to somewhere in your function and see if that fixes it.

Admittedly, not sure why `is_file` would return true in this case, but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Still not sure why, but making sure to close it when I know the scope made it work every time.

Comment: Stil not sure what happens exactly, would be worth it to know what exactly causes it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I can not be sure, but I bet that the error is somewhere else and it's just projecting itself as you've described it.

In order to test and debug your code, you need to use a debugger like [**PDT**](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). But then the problem is that you need to debug a part of your code that is out of debugger's reach, the session writer! To overcome this problem you can use [session_write_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). You can put it somewhere at the end of your bootstrap or if you don't have one, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
function shutdown_function()
{
    session_write_close();
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown_function');
```

Then by setting a break point, you can start debugging your session code from here. Let me know if I win the bet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$save_handler = new DB();
session_set_save_handler($save_handler, true);
```

then map read, write, etc functions inside your class. i faced a similar issue(bizarre random errors about a class not being found) implementing another user's custom save handler workaround for HHVM with redis, and this is how i fixed it. if you are using HipHopVirtualMachine (or possibly some other type of JIT compiler or app cache), sometimes your project can cache some functions without updating, producing odd errors like this. usually a restart of the fastcgi daemon and adding white space to one of your files is enough to force it to re interpret your project.

Comment: The DB class is not the save handler. It is just used in the function to make a call to the database. The function this code resides in is the `sess_write` function.

Comment: Thanks for your insight though. As this works fine on about 6 other projects. It's only one that is giving me a fit like this. I will look into it and also may refactor to use a class implementing `SessionHandlerInterface` instead of functions.